# Steam again starting game download after installing Rage

Tags: pc, steam, rage

I bought Rage from an online store yesterday. I activated the game and its DLCs (Anarchy Edition and Sewer Missions). After activation the game showed the popup:

> Game already registered.

And after that it installed the game taking 20 GB space. Now when I started the game, the steam asked for updating the game and started downloading 17 GB of update. I also tried opening game in offline steam mode, but steam said that

> Game is not ready to be played in offline mode.

I also tried a suggestion of validating local data integrity of the game on some forum, and it validated the data 100%, but still no use. Steam is still downloading that 17 GB update.

I have a very low Internet connection speed, and to download this amount of data will take a month. I can't wait for that long -- how can I bypass the update?

Comment: Once Steam has begun an update I don't think it can be stopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I solved it by uninstalling and removing everything related to Rage from Steam and reinstalling Rage. Also don't forget to update your graphics driver.

Answer (score 2):

Give your computer stats?  Maybe u have downloaded more than one of them.  Look into your library.  If there is more than one of "Rage" than  it will update all of them at once hence taking up more gb space on your cpu